# MKMapView annotation click event

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

When I click on the pin, annotation view is opened with detailed disclosure button.
When I touch detailed disclosure button next view is called,I need same functionality when I touch on annotation.

Answer (score 6):

There is one delegate [method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html) in MKMapViewDelegate, When you select an annotation this method will help you to track which annotation got selected and than you may message to any selector you want ;).

```
mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:
```

Tells the delegate that one of its annotation views was selected.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
Parameters
mapView
```

The map view containing the annotation view.
view
The annotation view that was selected.
Discussion

You can use this method to track changes in the selection state of annotation views.

Availability
Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
Declared In
MKMapView.h

Comment: Hi I used this method to show the details of the pin. Once I click on the pin, annotation opens which shows the information about event with detail disclosure button. Now when i touch to the detail disclosure button it goes to next view. But when I touche to anywhere on this information(annotation view) user should able to go to next view. I need a event when user click on this. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code -

```
UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

rightButton.tag = annotationIndex;

[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
```

In this "showDetails" should be your custom IBAction in which you code your functionality.

Comment: He asked for responding tap on annotation and not right accessory button ;)